# Filter and sorter disable together for some of the column in table sorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I want to disable the sorter and filter together for some of the columns.
But when i do below functions it is disabling wither one of them(sorter or filter)

### My code below

```
  $('.tablesorter').tablesorter({
  theme: 'blue',
  widthFixed: true,
  widgets: [ 'stickyHeaders', 'columnSelector','filter'],
 textExtraction: function(node, table, cellIndex){
    return $(node).text().replace(/\s'/g,'');
  },
headers: {{6: { sorter: false},7: { sorter: false},8: { sorter: false},6: { filter: false},7: {   filter: false},8: { filter: false}},
  widgetOptions : {


  // Use the $.tablesorter.storage utility to save the most recent filters
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy",
  filter_serversideFiltering: true,
  filter_saveFilters : false,
  // jQuery selector string of an element used to reset the filters
  filter_reset : 'button.reset',
  // add custom selector elements to the filter row
  filter_formatter : {
    /*0 : function($cell, indx){
      return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.uiDatepicker( $cell, indx, {     
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear : true
      });
    },*/
    // Alphanumeric (match)
    4 : function($cell, indx){
      return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.select2( $cell, indx, {
        match : true,         // adds "filter-match" to header
       // cellText : 'Select: ', // Cell text
        width: '90%',         // adjusted width to allow for cell text
        value: [<%=createdBy%>], // initial values
        placeholder: "Search.."

      });
    },
    5 : function($cell, indx){
      return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.select2( $cell, indx, {
        match : true,         // adds "filter-match" to header
       // cellText : 'Select: ', // Cell text
        width: '90%',         // adjusted width to allow for cell text
        value: [<%=actions%>], // initial values
        placeholder: "Search.."
      });
    },
  0 : function($cell, indx){
      return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.uiDatepicker( $cell, indx, {
         from : new Date(), // default from date
         to   : new Date(),  // default to date
       // dateFormat : 'dd/MON/yy',
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        cellText : "",
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"

      });
    }

    /*0 : function($cell, indx){
        return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.uiDateCompare( $cell, indx, {
            cellText : '', // text added before the input
            compare : ['After', 'Before' ],
            selected : 3,
            // jQuery UI datepicker options
            // defaultDate : '1/1/2014', // default date
            changeMonth : true,
            changeYear : true,
            placeholder: "Date",
            dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy'
          });
    }*/
  },



  // option added in v2.16.0
  filter_selectSource : {
    // Alphanumeric match (prefix only)
    // added as select2 options (you could also use select2 data option)
    4 : function(table, column) {
      return [<%=createdBy%>];
    },
    5 : function(table, column) {
      return [<%=actions%>];
    },
  },

  filter_placeholder : {
    from : 'From...',
    to   : 'To...'
  }

},
```

});

Above this function init the table sorter and filter functions as well.
Let me know if anyone wants more details?
Can someone help me on this?

Comment: can you add the full js code of your tablesorter?

Comment: @Vdesign Can u abe able to identify this one?

Comment: Would setting [`parser:false`](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#parsers) on a column work for you?

Comment: where do i put the parser:false ?

Comment: In the [`headers` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#headers), or as a class name (`parser-false`) in the header cell.